# Accessing UIViewController on button click and display on a UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have a `ViewController embedded` in a `container view`. The ViewController has 5 buttons. When I click on the a button, it should display another viewController to which the button is segued to, in a UIView.

To better explain the question, following is an image.

[image]

For instance, when I click on Button1, it should display the contents of the brown viewController in the UIView with the blue color.

I sort of want the functionality of a tab bar but want to put buttons in place of tab bar items.

How can I achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: Why not use a UITabbar?

Comment: You may want to take a look at container views, [here's](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/07/21/ios-container-views/) an example.